# VB.Net - How to compare 2 columns in GridView as numbers?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a GridView which I plan to add different colors in each row based on certain conditions.

One such condition is to color the row in a specific color if a number in column 6 is higher than the number in column 7.

```
 If e.Row.Cells(6).Text > e.Row.Cells(7).Text Then
            e.Row.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FDD533")
 Else
```

However, when I test the code it seems to only change the color when the left most value in column 6 is larger than column 7, regardless of the fact that column 6 is in the hundreds, while column 7 is in the thousands.

I believe the cause is coming from me using `text` in the `If` statement. However, any instance of number I can think to change doesn't seem to fit into the code:

```
If e.Row.Cells(6).Number > e.Row.Cells(7).Number Then
```

or

```
If e.Row.Cells(6).Integer > e.Row.Cells(7).Integer Then
```

These example gives me a message saying

```
'Number' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell'
```

What else can I use that is compatible with the current code?

Comment: Can you try Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells(6).Text)? Because I believe you're only missing a cast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you are missing a casting. I'm not sure if you're comparing only **Integers** or **complex numbers**, if you don't know I recommend you to cast directly to **doubles**:

```
If Convert.ToDouble(e.Row.Cells(6).Text) > Convert.ToDouble(e.Row.Cells(7).Text) Then
      e.Row.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FDD533")
Else
```

**Convert.ToDouble** will convert any text to number.

**More info about casting:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-number

https://www.dotnetheaven.com/article/casting-integer-to-long-single-and-double-using-vb.net

If you might have some **empty values** you can use the **TryCast**:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/trycast-operator

Comment: "Convert.ToDouble will convert any text to number." Not quite. Some strings, of course, cannot be converted and will cause an exception. That is why TryParse exists.